# Classification of Symmetric Spaces of Dimension $n$ and Rank $k$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, symmetric-spaces

(Rather than edit, I'm making a new post.)

In [Classification of Closed, Locally Symmetric Spaces of Dimension $n$ and Rank $k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314351/classification-of-closed-locally-symmetric-spaces-of-dimension-n-and-rank-k), I asked about closed, locally symmetric spaces. I now realize what I really meant to ask about were simply-connected symmetric spaces (the universal covers of closed, locally symmetric spaces).

So, having read the referenced question, is there a classification by rank of simply-connected symmetric spaces of dimension $n$? To ask the same thing slightly differently, in relation to Helgason's classification of symmetric spaces in *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces* by dimension, is there a (convenient?) way to arrange them in a given dimension by rank? [I'm new to symmetric spaces; do people simply think of them as "rank 1", "rank $n$", and "higher rank (excluding rank $n$?)"? There might be theorems that are true only for, say, rank 3 symmetric spaces in a given dimension $n \ge 5$.]

Comment: The classical classification is not by rank per se but by the *type* which is primarily determined by the Weyl group. Helgason has it, of course. Rank is only one of the parameters (important one, of course).

Comment: Additionally, my suggestion is to spend time understanding the standard classification. By the time you are done, chances are, you will not longer be interested in alternatives (there is none, afaik).

Comment: OK, I will memorize Helgason's classification

Comment: Don't memorize, but **understand**! Start with the classification of complex (or compact) Lie groups, since the classification of symmetric spaces is a generalization.

Comment: "Dynkin diagrams, here I come!"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Classification_of_semisimple_Lie_algebras

Comment: Yes, Dynkin diagrams...